# joomla 2.5 suddenly stripping tags

Tags: joomla2.5

I am working in Joomla 2.5 and had to install a wysiwyg editor for the client. I have ckeditor and jceditor installed. After enabling one of them every time an article is saved the image tags are stripped. The iframe gets through. All paths are correct and code is clean. I have gone and turned no filtering on for all user groups changed editors, no editors and still stripping.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thx

Comment: This applies to TinyMCE so not sure if it helps: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/articles/add-iframe

Comment: Nope doesn't apply. Doesn't seem to matter which editor I use they all strip the tags. Joomla is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with many editors but not this one.
please try [JCE](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/) and problem should go away